# Pushing or Pulling notifications

Tags: java, android, ios, mobile, push-notification

We want to implement a back end server [Java EE] for mobile application that sends notification to mobile on some events, I'm asking about the best/simplest approach whether Pushing or Pulling notifications, here you are my ideas/questions
1-  The requirement is to send instantly the notifications to the mobile as long as the application is running no need to send if it's not running
2- I read that to push notifications to IOS or Android, I will need to connect to apple/google notifications servers, I felt that this is complicated especially that it requires low level socket programming, but based on number 1 and the project has limited time and budget, do we really need pushing ? and is it really complex
3- I read that pulling date may drain battery and consume data, but what if implementing a simple job on the mobile that runs only 3 or 4 times a day, invoking a simple web service on back end server asking for the notifications
P.S will be much appreciated if you can provide some tutorials for similar cases :)

Answer (score 1):

1) If you're application is already running, is it connecting to the same location anyways? If so you might as well pull for the notifications at that point. However, if the app isn't actively connecting, i would attempt to avoid pulling.

2) Interacting with Notification servers on google and apple site directly, can indeed be a cumbersome task. However there are companies that have made this much easier for you. The advantage of using companies like urbanairship, xtify and mblox will get you started with sending push messages in minutes. (for an example take a look at http://developer.mblox.com/docs/ in the tutorial section).

3) depending on the data you try to present, end users now a days are used to instant data. I can't imagine a service whereby pulling 3 to 4 times a day is sufficient, however if your use case is truly limited to 4 times a day, and there is no other activity going on in the background process you create for this, you might as well have the background process running. But do think this through carefully... If at any point in time you want to increase the number of times a day you read, you might soon get to the point where a rewrite is needed to ensure end user satisfaction.